# Ajax POST to Python variable for processing

Tags: python, ajax

Long story short, i had a fully functional WebApp with PHP back end and IIS as the server, im now forced to remove PHP all together as its not an allowed language anymore. Im going thru python learning as an alternative to PHP and trying to simulate most of the functionality i had before with PHP. particularly the sending and procesing of data and returning of results which was rather easy in PHP where i had an AJAX POST and in PHP i would receive the data as usual with:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
```

and the proceed and process the data to MySQL or whatever and then:

```
echo 'Success';
```

a result. I already have python and CGI installed for IIS and it seems to be working as a simple Hello World script works fine, how would i go about the same with python?

This is my POST that contains 3 variables with data. How can i receive that data in python(variables?), process it, then return a result('a string' for example) for my callback function?

```
 $.post(
        'register.py',
        {login: login, batch: batch, who: code},
        function (data) {
            $('#registerinsert').html(data);
        }
    );
```

Ive looked at many other questions but none seem to make much sense to me, bear in mind im just starting with python and some things still escape me...

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You should look at the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your data to the python script through an ajax call:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "script.py",
            async: false,
            data: {param: data}
 });
 return jqXHR.responseText;
```

in your Python script you can return a value through the `print` function. Simply `print data` will return a string to your ajaxRequest which you can catch using `.responseText`. This string can ofcourse be a JSON string aswell.

There are some issues to worry about running Python on your server, for me my python script should always have the following at the top else my browser returns 500 errors

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
```